# Mac Pages 09: Won't let me use Bookmarks and Hyperlinks within a document in layout

Tags: hyperlink, iwork-pages

In the layout format of a pages document, I am unable to create bookmarks of the text inside of text boxes.  It will not let me add a bookmark.  I can only add a bookmark when I am using the word processing format, although not if the text in word processing is inside of a text box.  All the help windows indicate that you should be able to create a bookmark with text inside a textbox.

Please help!  Is there a setting I need to change or something I'm doing wrong.  How can I create a bookmark to then hyperlink to within a document in layout format of Pages 09?

Thanks!